# adding new address families (AF_xxx)

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel

I came across the kernel driver code implementing some sort of IGMP snooping backend and as part of its functionalilty it creates a new socket address family, AF_IGMPSNOOP, but actually implements just a few operations for this type of socket:

```
static struct proto_ops igmp_snoop_ops = {
   family:       AF_IGMP_SNOOP,
   release:      _igmp_snoop_sock_release,
   bind:         sock_no_bind,
   connect:      sock_no_connect,
   socketpair:   sock_no_socketpair,
   accept:       sock_no_accept,
   getname:      sock_no_getname,
   poll:         datagram_poll,
   ioctl:        sock_no_ioctl,
   listen:       sock_no_listen,
   shutdown:     sock_no_shutdown,
   setsockopt:   _igmp_snoop_setsockopt,
   getsockopt:   sock_no_getsockopt,
   sendmsg:      _igmp_snoop_sock_sendmsg,
   recvmsg:      _igmp_snoop_sock_recvmsg,
   mmap:         sock_no_mmap,
   sendpage:     sock_no_sendpage,
}
```

However from a user space perspective a socket is created as:

```
fd = socket (AF_IGMPSNOOP, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IGMP)
```

I'm wondering what is the rationale for adding a new family, while in fact a raw socket is being used to access the stack for IGMP packets? Would not it be the same to just create AF_INET raw socket and do the things?

Looking forward to hearing form you !
Thanks.

Mark